# Trouble calling and getting location in oncreate method from location listener android

Tags: android, sms, location

i need your help regarding the location update in android. Following is my code for getting location update and it is working fine. But it returns invalid message body when i get the stored variable with location in oncreate method of main class. After thorough research it seems that the variable i called in oncreate method is empty. Can you please tell me how to get the address as it appears in onlocationChanged Method. Thank you!

Calling class with oncreate method:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listener = new Mylocation();

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
             String address1= listener.getAddress();

           {
                sendSms(phone, message, false);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.i("Error Is ", e.toString());
            }

        }
```

location class:

```
class Mylocation implements LocationListener{

    double lat, lon;
    static final String address="";

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        //...

        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        address = GetAddressDetail(lat, lon);
        Log.i("Messge is", address); //working here 
        }

    public String getAddress(){ //not returning the address
        return address;
    }

public String GetAddressDetail(Double lat2, Double lon2)
    {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat2,lon2, 1);
            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i));
                }
                ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            }
            else{
                ret = "No Address returned!";
            }
}
        return ret;
}
}
```

Comment: Your `address` variable is final, meaning it can only be assigned once. Therefore reassigning it with the result of `GetAdressDetail` will not work.

Comment: It doesn't appear you have declared a value for `message` and you aren't showing instantiation of it.

Comment: @LeonLucardie, though address is declared final it is still working in that part. The only thing is i cant call that value via getAddress in oncreate method of android

Comment: @Asok, It is still the same after i made the change.

Comment: try using best provider instead of network provider

Comment: When you're calling getAddress(), are you sure the onLocationChanged has been fired already? (considering you're calling it the line directly after starting to probe for locations)

Comment: @LeonLucardie, I am not getting properly what do you mean. Can you please share me your rough coding of doing it.

Comment: After you call `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);` you immediatly call `String address1= listener.getAddress();`. Are you sure the `onLocationChanged` has already been run when you call that variable?

Comment: @LeonLucardie, thats what i am thinking as well. Because it returns null as per the invalid message body. can you share me your way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the address after you've retrieved it?

Comment: @send as body of sms to another android phone.

Comment: Alright. I've added a answer showing a little example how it could be accomplished to only send a SMS after onLocationChange has been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling getAdress directly after you set the locationmanager to probe for a location. The onLocationChanged method probably hasn't been called yet when you call getAddress this way. I would recommend changing it to something like below to make sure it has been called:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      listener = new Mylocation();

      locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,new LocationListener(){
           @Override    
           public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           //...

              long lat = location.getLatitude();
              long lon = location.getLongitude();
              String address = GetAddressDetail(lat, lon);
              //Do whatever you want to do with the address here, maybe add them to the message or something like that.
              sendSms(phone, message, false);
           }
      });

}

public String GetAddressDetail(Double lat2, Double lon2)
{
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat2,lon2, 1);
            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i));
                }
                ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            }
            else{
                ret = "No Address returned!";
            }
        }
        return ret;
}
```

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I have tried the same thing as you did but the main thing you realized is the sendSMS within the listener. It worked and thank you for you patience and time. BTW, do you think is it right way for sending location to another phone.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your variables are initialized properly. I don't see evidence of this in the question so I am just checking.

```
// Instantiation
Mylocation listener;
String phone;
String message;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialization
    listener = new Mylocation(this);
    phone = "";
    message = "";

    // These two lines aren't really necessary,
    // this should be in your MyLocation class      
    //locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);

    // Add this line, we are going to initialize this class 
    // and make sure that address gets set
    listener = new Mylocation();
    String address1 = listener.getAddress();

    try {
        // If neither phone nor message is empty lets sendSms()
        if (!phone.isEmpty() || !message.isEmpty()) {
            sendSms(phone, message, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Error Is ", e.toString());
    }

}
```

---

Change the `String address` to private and in the getter try `return this.address;`

```
class Mylocation implements LocationListener {

    double lat, lon;
    // Let's make this private so it can't be accessed directly, 
    // since you have the setter and getter.
    private String address = "";

    // Make sure you are overriding this method
    @Override    
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        /** ... */
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lon = location.getLongitude();
        address = GetAddressDetail(lat, lon);
        Log.i("Messge is", address);
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return (address.isEmpty()) ? "Address not set" : this.address;
    }

    public String GetAddressDetail(Double lat2, Double lon2) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat2,lon2, 1);
            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i));
                }
                ret = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            }
            else{
                ret = "No Address returned!";
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

I made changes to your code in my answer above, check the comments. I am also going to suggest additional methods for your `MyLocation` class:

```
class Mylocation implements LocationListener {
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    private Context activityContext;

    // The initializing method, this fires off first 
    // when a new instance of the class is created
    public MyLocation(Context context) {
        this.activityContext = context;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) activityContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                MIN_TIME, 
                MIN_DISTANCE, 
                this
            );
        }

        getLocation();
    }

    private double lat;
    private double lon;

    public double getLat() {
        return this.lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return this.lng;
    }

    public void getLocation() {
        if (location == null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                    // Set the coordinate variables
                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    lon = location.getLongitude();
                    Log.i("Network", "Lat: " + latitude + " / Lng: " + longitude);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the coding. Well, it is working with the pre-defined string for the variable message which i am sending as SMS. The only thing is i want to have the message with the location i got from onLocationChanged() from the follow up coding.

Comment: There is no problem with the listener but the only problem is getting address from it in oncreate and sending sms as message value.

Comment: I made a few more changes to help you along. See above Edit for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. I will use some portion of you coding in mine. Thanks